# In the Windows 10/11 Start menu, is there a way to set the search term to program/file/etc. association?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-11, file-association, windows-search

As you use the startup search and pick which program (or file/folder/etc.) you want to run, the search term and also the incomplete search term gets associated to that program. Like for example I have been using notepad++ as my text editor for notes and now it is associated with "text", "tex", "te" for me. I want to switch to using Evernote and have already changed the file association .txt to open in Evernote and not notepad++ anymore, however when I write "text" in windows startup menu search, notepad++ is still the first thing that comes up. So I want to change it manually so that "text", and possibly also "tex" and "te" and maybe even "t" give me Evernote as my first option, so I only have to press enter.

By the way, I say Windows 10/11 because my main computer is Windows 11 but I also have a second one running Windows 10.

Now, this is a specific example, but there are a few other instances where I want to change the association manually. I suppose one easy way to accomplish this is maybe to uninstall Notepad++, but I really just want to have the power to override the priority of programs for certain search terms manually. So if anyone knows a way, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Search allows you to specify [*kind*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/building-property-handlers-user-friendly-kind-names) and *extension*, for example:

```
folder:*conrad* AND ext:epub
```

or

```
folder:*conrad* AND kind:picture
```

The mapping of *kind* to *extension* is at

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\KindMap
```

To change that mapping, change a value.

As for mapping *extensions*, look at `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\`. For example, on this machine, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt` is defined (`Default`) as a `Notepad++_file`. One could either change the value of `Default`, or find the key `Notepad++_file` and change its value. There are a number of levels of indirection, making this task prone to error.

[image: .txt extension]

*Edit the Registry with caution,* because an error can make a machine unbootable, where even a Restore Point cannot salvage it -- only a restore from *full disk image* (as I've found through experience).